# Kaehler manifold of dimension 6 not homotopy equivalent to a complex submanifold of $\mathbb{C}P^n$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Does there exist a closed Kaehler manifold of real dimension 6 that is not homotopy equivalent to a complex submanifold of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ for some integer $n$?

Comment: I’m sure you’re aware of this, but just to remark that the answer in “yes” in all real dimensions $\geq 8$ due to Voisin https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312032 (and the answer is “no” in dimensions $\leq 4$). I would guess this problem is still open.